# angularjs checkbox ng-model can't select to selectedModel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I can't bind for CRUD update function. If I click checkbox, it added to selectedMembers list. 
These are $scope.selectedMembers and $scope.members from database

```
selectedMembers 
[{"id":"3","name":"john","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"5","name":"paul","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null}]

Members
[{"id":"1","name":"Mac","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"2","name":"cathy","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"3","name":"john","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"4","name":"ryan","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"5","name":"paul","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null}]
new selectedMembers

[{"id":"3","name":"john","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"5","name":"paul","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null},
{"id":"4","name":"ryan","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null}
{"id":"5","name":"paul","created_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","updated_at":"2015-03-20 10:27:02","deleted_at":null}]
```

This is html by ng-repeat

```
<span  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="member in members">
    <input type="checkbox" name="members[]" value="{{member.id}}" ng-model="selectedMembers" ng-click="toggleCheck(member)" > {{member.name}}
</span>
```

This is toggleCheck function

```
scope.toggleCheck = function (member) {
        if ($scope.selectedMembers.indexOf(member) === -1) {
            $scope.selectedMembers.push(member);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedMembers.splice($scope.selectedMembers.indexOf(member), 1);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution from there. http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/sluAF

Hope it would be helpful.

This is in controller.

```
    $scope.isChecked = function(id){
      var match = false;
      for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.selectedMembers.length; i++) {
        if($scope.selectedMembers[i].id == id){
          match = true;
        }
      }
      return match;
    };

    $scope.sync = function(bool, member){
      if(bool){
        // add item
        $scope.selectedMembers.push(member);
      } else {
        // remove item
        for(var i=0 ; i < $scope.selectedMembers.length; i++) {
          if($scope.selectedMembers[i].id == member.id){
            $scope.selectedMembers.splice(i,1);
          }
        }      
      }
    };
```

This is ng-repeat in html.

```
<span  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="member in members">
    <input type="checkbox" name="members[]" ng-change="sync(bool, member)" ng-model="bool" ng-checked="isChecked(member.id)" > {{member.name}}
</span>
```